# How to store states in React JS using useReducer?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a component ( let's call it a grandparent component ) , by default it has an input box , ( > ) arrow and an add button , whenever I click on Add button , a new input box will get generated.Now let's come to main part whenever I click on ( > ) button a new component should open up and in that also a default input box,(> will be present with a same add button , if I add something in it and click on (>) button a new component should open up and same an input box , (>) icon and add button

So now the thing is , its forming a tree structure:

```js
const finalStructure = {
    "category": {
      "agriculture" : ["5 hectares" , "10 hectates" , "15 hectares"],
      "automobile" : ["bus" , "car" , "truck"],
      "farming": ["wheat" , "rice" , "maida"]
    }, 
    "product": {
      "face": "white-toned",
      "skin": "healthy"
    }
  };
```

See carefully here "category " is the first value I enter in grandparent component and  [ "agricluture " , "automobile" , "automotive" ] are the three options I enter in parent component and then the correspondin values to agriculture is what I entered in child component.

Now the question is:
How do I maintain a relation between these 3 components [ grandparent , parent and child ]
Till now I tried to use stated and assign empty objects to input value but the thing how to store the values so that if I refer that in future , the values remain retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the use of `useContext()` and `useReducer()`.

The `useContext()` hook is there for providing the relevant values to the subcomponents. It is key for using `useReducer()` effectively in React `cross-component` state management.

But first we have to `createContext()` before using `useContext()`.

**`createContext()` example:**

```
// ParentComponent.js

export const context = React.createContext({ myDefault: "value" });
...

const { Provider } = context;

return (
  <>
    <Provider value={{ myCustom: "value" }}>
      <MyComponent />
    </Provder>
    <NoProviderComponent />
  </>
)
```

Now all components inside `Provider` component will have access to the provided value `{myCustom: "value"}` while components outside the `Provider` can only access `{myDefault: "value"}`.

**`useContext()` example:**

```
// MyComponent

import { context } from "./ParentComponent.js";

const value = useContext(context);

console.log(value);       // will log `{ myCustom: "value" }`
```

```
// NoProviderComponent

import { context } from "./ParentComponent.js";

const value = useContext(context);

console.log(value);       // will log `{ myDefault: "value" }`
```

With the help of `useReducer()` you can centralize state handling inside of a simple function, conventionally (redux) they work with `action` objects that always have a `type` and some sort of `value`/`payload`.

Here I have an example of a state that is a list of file objects.

**`useReducer()` example:**

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch(action) {
    case "ADD_FILE":
      return [
        ...state,
        payload
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, []);
```

```
...
return (
  <button onClick={() =>
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_FILE", payload: YOUR_FILE_OBJECT})}>
    Add me on click!
  </button>
)
```

### Result

You can combine all of that in one `store.js` file:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  category: {},
  product: {},
};
const store = createContext();
const { Provider } = store;

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_NEW_CATEGORY":
        return {
          ...state,
          category: {
            ...state.category,
            [action.value]: [],
          },
        };
      case "ADD_TO_CATEGORY":
        return {
          ...state,
          category: {
            ...state.category,
            [action.value]: [...state.category[action.value], action.payload],
          },
        };
      case "ADD_PRODUCT":
        return {
          ...state,
          product: {
            ...state.product,
            ...action.payload,
          },
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export { store, StateProvider };
```

And using that in your `index.js`:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';
import { StateProvider } from './store.js';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StateProvider>
    <App />
  </StateProvider>
);
```

Now you can edit the state in any child component like that:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { store } from "./store.js";

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const globalState = useContext(store);
  const { state, dispatch } = globalState;

  // Adding new category
  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_NEW_CATEGORY",
    value: "farming",
  });

  // Adding to category
  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TO_CATEGORY",
    value: "farming",
    payload: ["wheat", "rice", "maida"],
  });

  // Adding product
  dispatch({
    type: "ADD_PRODUCT",
    payload: { face: "white-toned" },
  });
};
```